# AngularJS / Material: why the expression is not evaluated?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I do not understand why the expression "{{isMultiple}}" is not evaluated in this code:

HTML:

```
<md-input-container style="width: 30%;">
   <label>{{label}}</label>
   <md-select ng-model="choice" multiple="{{isMultiple}}">
     <md-option value="1">Option 1</md-option>
     <md-option value="2">Option 2</md-option>
     <md-option value="3">Option 3</md-option>
   </md-select>
 </md-input-container>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.isMultiple = false;
    $scope.choice = "";
    $scope.label = "MyLabel";
}
```

Full code on Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/a5yCLW?p=preview

The Dropdown control should NOT be multi-selectable in this example.

Comment: I think it's a bug in angular-material. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179869/how-to-bind-to-multiple-in-md-select-inside-directive/39181060#39181060) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pass an expression to the attribute `multiple`, [according to the documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect):

[image]

However, one way around this is to create the `md-select` in the code - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/XjJaWz?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
<md-input-container id="myInputContainer" style="width: 30%;">
   <label>{{label}}</label>
 </md-input-container>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache', 'ngDialog'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $element, $compile) {
  var myInputContainer = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#myInputContainer')),
      mdSelect,
      mdSelectElement;

  $scope.options = [
    {value: 1, label: "Option 1"},
    {value: 2, label: "Option 2"},
    {value: 3, label: "Option 3"}
  ]
  $scope.isMultiple = false;
  $scope.choice = "";
  $scope.label = "MyLabel";

  mdSelect = "<md-select ng-model='choice' multiple='" + $scope.isMultiple + "'>" +
    "<md-option ng-repeat='option in options' value='{{option.value}}'>{{option.label}}</md-option>" +
    "</md-select>";
  mdSelectElement = angular.element(mdSelect);
  myInputContainer.append(mdSelectElement);
  $compile(myInputContainer)($scope);
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely right @camdem_kid! I took for granted that mutliple could receive an expression instead of a simple boolean value. Next time, I will re-check the doc ;)  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

well if you could do

multiple="false"

then you won't get checkboxes but it work quiet simple user can select only one value as expected. checkbox means there could be more then one selection could be made.

Comment: That is true, but the dropdown will be generated, and, depending on the database data, the dropdown should be multiselect or not.