# Can't disable `multiple` attribute on angular material mdSelect when trying to use parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Can't disable `multiple` attribute on angular material mdSelect when trying to use parameter.  If I use a constant, it works:

```
<md-select ng-model="size"
           multiple="false">
```

But if I try to use a scope variable instead, it doesn't:
HTML:

```
<md-select ng-model="size"
           multiple="isMultiValue">
```

JS:

```
$scope.isMultiValue = false;
```

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzaGKd?editors=1010#anon-login

Comment: See my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39331150/782358

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179869/how-to-bind-to-multiple-in-md-select-inside-directive/39181060#39181060

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-multiple instead

```
<md-select ng-model="size"
       ng-multiple="isMultiValue">
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrVjBE)

Comment: added demo in answer

Comment: With ng-multiple true, you are losing the checkbox of select values. Try to set multiple="true" and you'll see the difference